# how can i make the images on my site at the same height

Tags: html

how can i solve this problem  [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mujmk.png)

this is the link of my website http://al-moltazem.com/

how can i fix it plz ??

```css
.container .one-third.column {
    width: 300px;
}
.gallery .item img, .portfolio .item img, .recent-work .item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.gallery .item a, .gallery .item img, .portfolio .item a, .portfolio .item img, .recent-work .item a, .recent-work .item img {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have empty posts there in your website. If you remove your empty posts everything will be all right.

Comment: yes i added a post without featured image so this images did not displayed on the page is this the problem ?

Comment: yes. Because of empty posts images doesn't appear, but the margins of the outer div still there, because of that other posts shifts down.

I highlighted empty div, check it out:
http://imgur.com/a/d3erR